# Does Firebase synchronization only retrieve changed nodes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I listen to a node that has previously retrieved and is locally cached with persistence enabled, can I expect that only new nodes will be retrieved? Can I expect the same with an application restart?

The use case is: I have a node that has about 0-1000 child nodes and several times a day some nodes are added and old ones removed (for maintenance).

The easiest to implement is to maintain the list as is and hope that Firebase will play nicely with cached data. If not I can implement a local cache and manually remove nodes to retrieve only the new ones each time, but that is a lot more work.t